# How can I pass a Date to trandate while creating an Invoice with SuiteScript 2.0

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I created **RESTlet** which makes it easier to create new Invoice via simple web page with multiple inputs and dropdowns. I'm sending date as **D-M-YYYY** string using json called invoiceInfo, the date string is a value of trandate.
On the script *(Suitescript 2.0)* I connect to, I split the trandate, then create a Date object *(I use new Number not because of my stupidity, it just works only that way)*. Then I format the date to Netsuite's desireable format using `format.format`. After that I set a value of trandate using formatted date.

```
var splitedDate = invoiceInfo.trandate.split("-");
var dateObj = new Date(new Number(splitedDate[0]).valueOf(), (new Number(splitedDate[1]).valueOf()) - 1, new Number(splitedDate[2]).valueOf(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

var ffDate = format.format({
    value: dateObj,
    type: format.Type.DATE
});

invoiceRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: "trandate",
    value: ffDate,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});
```

When submitting the Invoice *(dynamic mode is set as true)* I get an error at line **number 83**, which is this line

> invoiceRecord.setValue({
>        fieldId: "trandate",
>        value: ffDate,
>        ignoreFieldChange: true
>       });

And got an error like this:

```
{
    "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
    "name": "INVALID_FLD_VALUE",
    "message": "Invalid date value (must be D/M/YYYY)",
    "stack": ["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)", "<anonymous>(/SuiteScripts/Filip/_wystawianie_faktury_api.js:83)
    [...]
```

When I check it with log.debug I get this:

> "invoiceInfo.trandate" is (for example) "2019-03-15"
>
> "dateObj" is "2019-03-15T07:00:00.000Z"
>
> "ffDate" is "15/3/2019"

I have tried many options, for example:
-passing hardcoded date string "15/3/2019" I get the same error;
-I tried setText instead of setValue and got another error;
-I tried changing the date format in @HomeIcon -> Set Preferences and then gave the desired format hardcoded and it still didn't work;

Thanks for help

PS I'm kinda new at writing questions on stack. I tried my best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Invalid date value (must be D/M/YYYY)

This means `ffDate` is not a date object.

A few things to note first

1. [record.setValue](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4273155868.html) requires value to be dateTime object.
2. If you pass invalid dateTime value to [format.format](https://3626311-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4388843892.html), it returns `option.value` which is not a dateTime object.
3. If you have a date object, you don't need to format it before using `record.setValue`.
4. `setText` requires string to be properly formatted in user format, so its better to use `setValue` instead cause it handles all the conversion etc.

So what I suggest is, you pass date in ISO String to the RESTlet, which could easily be converted into date object in NetSuite(using new Date()) and then pass this object directly to `record.setValue`.

Comment: Now I get an error like this:

{\\\"type\\\":\\\"internal error\\\",\\\"code\\\":\\\"DATE_EXPECTED\\\",\\\"details\\\":\\\"You entered \\'null\\' into a field where a calendar date was expected.\\\\nPlease go back and change this value to the correct date.\\\",\\\"userEvent\\\":null,\\\"stackTrace\\\":[\\\"anonymous(N/serverRecordService)\\\",\\\"<anonymous>

When I look at debug I see new Date(invoiceInfo.trandate) as right Date object ("2019-03-05T00:00:00.000Z"). Do you have any other ideas? I'm stuck with it for a while for now.

Comment: could you provide your source JSON and code? as per NetSuite error log, you are setting null value for date field. There must be something wrong with your JSON on method to set value.

Comment: Somebody in my company made some wrong changes to the code, thats why it didnt work at all. When i deleted them it finally works! Still thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

```
var splitedDate = invoiceInfo.trandate.split("-");
var dateObj = new Date(new Number(splitedDate[0]).valueOf(), (new Number(splitedDate[1]).valueOf()) - 1, new Number(splitedDate[2]).valueOf(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

invoiceRecord.setValue({
    fieldId: "trandate",
    value: dateObj,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});
```

Explanation : setValue for a Date field accept a javascript DateObj so no need to format.